# Selecting Instant Winner on Web Application

Tags: web-applications, real-time, instant, gambling

I'm running a web application in which real time data is used to select a winner. My application is supposed to be selecting Instant winners rather than consolidating a day's worth of information/entries and selecting a winner via a draw. So it is that when a winner clicks the correct combination, they can either be the lucky winner or not. Currently, When a winner clicks the correct combination, the system checks the databse of entries and finds if the winner is of an entry that is divisible by 5 , if not they are unlucky but if yes, they are the winner and both receive the corresponding reply on the page that is redirected to after the click.

There are a specific number of prizes won each day which is computed by the number of clicks of the previous day. Also there are different prizes won on each day.

What I'd like to know is if there is another way ( a cleaner way) of randomizing how these winners are selected rather than running it the way I am. Ive tried to google but cant find a good answer. Im not a gambler so this is new for me. I basically want a way for my application to run "pinky pinky ponky..." for each real-time entry.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you could do. How about generating 5 random numbers between 1 and 10 and if 3 of them are the same the user wins.